# how can i sort multiple map array

Tags: java, grails

I' m trying to perform multiple map sort

> before sort data>>>.>>[[id:38, text:Improver], [id:27, text:Beginner]]

unable to sort using

> Collections.sort(data.id)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please consider @Dragonthoughts comment in order to get an answer ;)

Comment: Please clear your question first.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `Comparator`, for example.

```
Comparator<Developer> byName = 
    (Developer o1, Developer o2)->o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
```

Then

`Collections.sort(list, byName);`